# goldbach's conjecture algorithm shows "list index out of range" above a specific number

Tags: python, list, goldbach-conjecture

I am creating a program where the user can enter an even number between 4 and 5000 and the program will output a list of pairs of prime numbers that sum up the number provided in the input.

My program works fine to put all the prime numbers in a list and checks that the input is an even integer between 4 and 5000. For small inputs it works perfectly but for larger inputs it says that the "list index is out of range" and I have no idea why.

This is the code I used: (added comments to help)

---

```
global prime_numbers
prime_numbers=[]
user_number=0
def start():
    for i in range(5000):
        prime_test(i)

def prime_test(a):
    global prime_numbers
    x = True 
    for i in range(2, a):
            while x:
               if a%i == 0:
                   x = False
                   break
               else:
                   x = True
                   break


if x==True and a!=0 and a!=1:
    prime_numbers.append(a)
    #print(prime_numbers[int(len(prime_numbers)-1)])#
    #prints last digit/\ /\ /\ (for testing purposes)#
    if a==4999:
        user_input()
def user_input():
    user_number=input('please enter a whole even number between 4 and 5000:   ')
    #checks if user input is valid#
    try:
        #checks for a number#
        user_number=float(user_number)
        #checks for an integar#
        if user_number!=int(user_number):
            print('that is not a whole number')
            user_input()
        #checks for an even number#
        a=(user_number/2)
        if a!=int(a):
            print('that is not an even number')
            user_input()
        #checks it is inbetween 4 and 5000#
        elif user_number<4:
            print('that is not greater than or equal to 4')
            user_input()
        elif user_number>5000:
             print('that is not less than or equal to 5000')
             user_input()
        #if it is a valid input it procedes to the next section#
        else:
            q=int(user_number)
            goldbergs_conjecture(q)
    #the bit that checks to see if it is a number#
    except ValueError:
        print('that is not a number')
        user_input()
def goldbergs_conjecture(q):
    global prime_numbers
    for i in range(q):
        #serches for the first prime number in the list then the second ect...#
        x=prime_numbers[i]
        #y= user input minus a prime number form the list#
        y=q-x
        #if y is also in the list then it must be prime also so these are printed#
        if y in prime_numbers and x<(q/2):
            print(str(x) + ' + ' + str(y))
        #had to add this seperatly because if they were the same then this /\/\ didnt catch them#
        if y==x:
            print(str(x) + ' + ' + str(y))
#gives the user something to look at whilst the list is generating#    
print('loading...')
start()
```

---

For a small number this works perfectly e.g.

---

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py 
loading...
please enter a whole even number between 4 and 5000:   568
5 + 563
11 + 557
47 + 521
59 + 509
89 + 479
101 + 467
107 + 461
137 + 431
149 + 419
167 + 401
179 + 389
251 + 317
257 + 311
>>>
```

---

But for a larger number like 800, (actually its any number above 668 for some reason if that helps) then it says "IndexError: list index out of range"

---

```
>>> 
 RESTART: C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py 
loading...
please enter a whole even number between 4 and 5000:   800
3 + 797
13 + 787
31 + 769
43 + 757
61 + 739
67 + 733
73 + 727
109 + 691
127 + 673
139 + 661
157 + 643
181 + 619
193 + 607
199 + 601
223 + 577
229 + 571
277 + 523
313 + 487
337 + 463
367 + 433
379 + 421
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py", line 72, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py", line 6, in start
    prime_test(i)
  File "C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py", line 26, in prime_test
    user_input()
  File "C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py", line 52, in user_input
    goldbergs_conjecture(q)
  File "C:\!A-level cs preparation\9th problem, goldbach's conjecture\main code first attempt.py", line 61, in goldbergs_conjecture
    x=prime_numbers[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

---

I have no idea why this isn't working after 668.

Comment: Calling the user input function upon invalid input detection could lead to a stack overflow in the worst case, by the way. This probably isn't in the scope of the assignment though.

Comment: Noticed a few things. **1.** The `global` statement is only useful when you want to *modify* a global in a non-global scope. **2.** The if block isn't properly indented **3.** Don't mix logic and user input **4.** `x == True` is the same as `x`, unless `x` overloads `__eq__` in some strange way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my foremost advices: don't use try unless you really need it. It will hide code bugs. Avoid global variables unless you really need it. It makes your brain dizzy after a while.

In your code the second sin is the source of the problem. You are running a for loop in range(q) which points to prime_numbers[i]. Tying those indexes mean that both lists need to have the same size, or primenumbers should be smaller than q. Write `print(i)` and print(len(prime_numbers)), in the beginning of your `for i in range(q)` loop. You will see that the script breaks when i > len(prime_numbers)

To avoid the try, write regex cases for your input.
To avoid the global, pass the list as a function argument, or run the loop on the prime_number list.

Hope this helps.

Comment: probably should have explained in the question, im just about to start my a levels so my knowlage is quite limited, eg i have no clue what a regex case is or how i could impliment it (i would apreciate it if you could explain).

Comment: wrote previous comment like 20 mins ago, just forgot to hit send, but during that time i was looking at the code, origionally i tried making it so it generated 5000 prime numbers but it ages to process that. but then i managed to fix it by simply changing it from     `for i in range (q)`    to     `for i in range (len(prime_numbers))` which works fine, but i wouldnt have seen that without you pointing out why it went wrong, so thankyou.

Comment: and just as an extra, to further my knowlage, so dont feel required to answer this, what is bad about `try` and how does it hide bugs? and simmilar thing about globals, why not use them? finally ive been told previously that i shouldnt call functions from within themselves (my CAU had a function in a function in a function inside another function, many times) but nobody has ever explained why not, whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

You are looping (in `goldbergs_conjecture()`) over `range(q)`, which can be anywhere from 4..5000.

But you are looking for this value: `x=prime_numbers[i]` which is an index into the `prime_numbers` list.

The `prime_numbers` list is not guaranteed to be as long as the `range(q)`, because (by definition) there are *fewer* prime numbers than integers in a given range.

Try printing out the length of the `prime_numbers` list before you ask for input. I'll bet it's close to 668.

Instead, you might try something like:

```
for prime in prime_numbers:
    if prime >= q:
        break

    ... do something with prime
```

To range over all the prime numbers less than `q`.

Comment: yeah there were 699 prime numbers, my original solution was to generate 5000 prime numbers but it took forever and was a terrible solution, i ended up just doing `for i in range (len(prime_numbers))` but thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0):

It breaks because number of prime numbers between 0 and 5000 is less than 5000 (it is probably less than 668 if you didn't make a mistake when telling about conditions for the error). I would advise use at line 59 use range(len(prime_numbers)) instead of range(q) (you can also use `enumerate` function)

Comment: i have to do this to a specification and it says the user has to enter a value between 4 and 5000,

Comment: yeah, i ended up figuring it out and doing that once i realised what was causing the problem, but thanks anyway